# LINQ "table" variable

Tags: asp.net, linq

I'm trying to turn a method I have right now into a more "generic" method that returns a string.  Right now, the method uses a statement like this:

```
var app = (from d in testContext.DAPPs
     where d.sserID == (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey
     select d).ToList();
```

I process the results of "app", add extra text etc.  The piece that changes (that I need to make more "generic") is the table name (DAPPs).  Is there a way I can do that, or, a better way to go around this all together?

Comment: Is this a a Linq 2 SQL or EntityFramework?

Comment: You should be more specific when tagging and naming your question, because linq can be used in alot of different frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to compose a Dynamic Linq Query.

There are a couple of ways to do this.  Have a look at the following:

**Dynamic Expressions in Linq to Sql**
 
http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/143814.aspx

**Using the LINQ Dynamic Query Library**
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx